# proxy list filter php script

Tags: php, filter, converters

please help me.
i want create proxy list filter in my web, but i get something problem. I want get result for proxy list like ip:port (ex: 123.456.2563:3128), but in my script i get more whitespace beetwen ip and port. How to replace it with ":" character?

this is my project page : http://devilzart.com/proxyfilter.html

and i want like this : http://www.proxy-listen.de/Proxy/Proxylistconverter.html

```
<?php

$listValue = "";

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    {
        if(!empty($_POST['list']))
        $res = preg_match_all("/\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\s+\d+/", $_POST['list'], $match);


        if($res)
        foreach($match[0] as $value) 
        $listValue .= $value."\n";

    }

?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
Enter proxy list to filter:
<br><textarea name="list" cols="50" rows="15"><?php echo trim($listValue); ?></textarea>
<p><input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Most likely you won't be needing any space characters at all, why not `str_replace(' ', '', $string)` ?

Comment: i am sorry, iam newbie in php, where I have to put str_replace(' ', '', $string) code?

Comment: `$listValue .= str_replace(' ', '', $value)."\n";`

Comment: thank you so much for your help friend, with a litle touch from your code, this is work fine: 

$listValue .= preg_replace('/\s+/', ":", $value)."\n";